# azure storage emulator throw 500 when try to use Task.WaitAlll to update multiple blobs simultaneously

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

i was trying to use Task.WaitAll to improve performance when try to update multiple blobs simultaneously

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://localhost.fiddler;");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
            container.CreateIfNotExists();

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob1 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob1");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob2");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob3 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob3");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob4 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob4");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob5 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob5");

            blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
            {
                RetryPolicy = new NoRetry()
            };
            var str = "To list the blobs in a container, first get a container reference. You can then use the container's ListBlobs method to retrieve the blobs and/or directories within it. To access the rich set of properties and methods for a returned IListBlobItem, you must cast it to a CloudBlockBlob, CloudPageBlob, or CloudBlobDirectory object. If the type is ";

            Task.WaitAll(UploadBlobAsync(blockBlob1, str), UploadBlobAsync(blockBlob2, str),  UploadBlobAsync(blockBlob3, str), UploadBlobAsync(blockBlob4, str), UploadBlobAsync(blockBlob5, str));            
        }


        private static async Task UploadBlobAsync(CloudBlockBlob blob, string content)
        {
            await blob.UploadTextAsync(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I found out the simulator sometime throw a 500 exception:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
Content-Length: 253
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 53a5fe0c-496a-4925-b87d-48cb59a7df37
x-ms-version: 2016-05-31
Date: Fri, 26 May 2017 16:46:28 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InternalError</Code><Message>Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
RequestId:53a5fe0c-496a-4925-b87d-48cb59a7df37
Time:2017-05-26T16:46:28.9534026Z</Message></Error>
```

If I enable the entry logic, it will succeed but will take much longer time than i thought, and i can see through fiddler that one of the blob operation always failed at the first time and succeed at the retry

it doesn't fail every time, but have a very high chance fail with the 500

This is tested with the emulator 5.0 and client library 8.1.3.  I didn't test this code with the azure cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

I also can repro this issue with 5 uploadblob tasks on my side with azure storage emulator v5.0. If the number of the tasks less than 5, then it can't be reproduced. That as you mentioned `one of the blob operation always failed at the first time.`  **But I can not reproduce it with Azure Cloud Storage, it works well with Azure Cloud Storage**. If any idea about storage emulator, we could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to Azure team.

Comment: as the emulator is not open sourced, i can not give further information, i believe it would be an easy fix for the azure team who is able to repeat the issue with the source code in hand. thanks for prompt response.

Comment: The storage emulator is used for us to familar with the development  and testing of storage. Base on my understanding it is not a good choice to test storage perfomance with storage emulator. More info about storage emulator  please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator). If it is useful, please mark it as solution that will let more communities easily search.

Comment: it is emulator, but it doesn't mean that it can have bugs. just my opinion. I am not testing performance with storage emulator.  I am writing code to improve my app performance, but i have to run my code locally against the emulator just for development purpose.

Comment: I agree with you. So if any idea about azure, we could give our feedback to azure team.